# Ping IP: connect: no such process

Tags: linux, ping

I am trying to figure out this issue and am getting a weird error.

We have two boxes which used to talk to one another on the network. Both are reachable via ssh from a separate network, which means they are able to talk to their default gateways just fine. When we try to ping from the linux machine to the linux machine, we get a bunch of timeouts.

When we try to ping from the linux box back, we are getting

```
connect: no such process.
```

I can't seem to find much documentation on this error, though there consistently seem to be references to VPN stuff when googling for this error. The

Comment: And you're not using IPsec?

Comment: Just got on the box - it looks like another one of my teammates had started working on VPN stuff with it and had left it off after creating a config file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ipsec0, and in that file was a line stating DST=<ip we're trying to reach>. Ran an ifdown on that interface and suddenly ping started working correctly. Looks like I'll need to brush up on IPSec stuff. So what actually causes this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a typical IPsec error that occurs when IPsec is misconfigured. Check your IPsec policy settings, your routing settings and make sure that racoon daemon is running.

Comment: Thanks! After speaking with my coworker and he had apparently started setting it up right before Thanksgiving. Appreciate the help!